# Find whether given strings are matching or not despite of having typing errors

Tags: php, mysql, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to develop a script which checks whether string is matching with any string or not?
I have table containing bulk data of rows.

```
recordId firstName lastName
    1       jhon      bagman
    2       kerio     control
    3       michele    levis
    4       roger       federrer
```

I had a bunch of strings as below

```
{
  [0]=>kerio
  [1]=>micehle
  [2]=>roget
  [3]=>jon
}
```

I want to find matching records from database anyhow by `mysql-query` or `php-code`.
Kerio must match kerio
micehle must match michele
roget must match roger
jon must match jhon

Means I want to search for matching string even though it contains typing errors as shown above.

I want this solution by any logic, means by `running a mysql query` or by `executing any "php code"` on all rows.

Answer (score 4):

A good, but slow/computational expensive method, is the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It lets you specify exactly how mangled a word has to be before it's not considered a match. MySQL doesn't support this directly, however, so you'd have to implement it in PHP.

A quick/dirty method directly in MySQL is to compare the [SOUNDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) values. It's quick, but also far less reliable:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table
WHERE SOUNDEX('kerio') IN (SOUNDEX(firstName), (SOUNDEX(lastName))
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks Marc, I am going to implement by using SOUNDEX() function. will let you know exact it worked for me or not?